# Design manager in IBM Rhapsody Designer for Systems Engineers

Tags: requirements, rhapsody

I am learning how to use IBM Rhapsody Designer for Systems Engineers 8.1.1 (on Windows 8) using course provided by IBM. In one of the chapters to import requirements into my project, I need to use Design manager which is supposed to be in the Tools tab. I can not find how to configure it. So should I download this Design manager separately or is there another way to configure it?

I would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM® Rational® Rhapsody® Design Manager is a web-based tool, built on the Jazz™ platform, for designing and modeling products, software, and systems. The capabilities enable stakeholders to contribute to and influence designs, enable software developers to collaborate and create better designs, and enable systems engineers to apply model-based systems engineering (MBSE) techniques.

Take a look here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/r/developerdesignmanager/

Comment: I tried to download it from Jazz.net, but I`ve got a weird message: _We were unable to validate your contact information as required by U.S. Export regulations. This happens sometimes in our automated process. We'll check it again manually within the next 24 hours and send an email prompting you to download again._

Comment: IBM website is very strict about downloading materials from countries where banned by US government. Change your IP to another country if you can